# MVC session variables storage Memory vs disk caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I store a number of large bitmaps that I make dynamically, using session variables using the following:

```
   public static MySession Current
        {
            get
            {
                MySession session =
                  (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
                if (session == null)
                {
                    session = new MySession();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
                }
                return session;
            }
        }
```

Would using disk caching is better, and if so is there a good example or documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing large items in `SessionState` is generally [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769338/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-session-to-store-state-in-high-traffic-websites) - it will limit the scalability of your application due to usage of server memory. Even if you move [SessionState to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178586.aspx), it will add to the IO and storage requirements of your app.

Below, I'm assuming you have a dynamic image generation action on a controller which is then referenced, e.g. `<img src='http://myserver/image/generate/wmAvatar' >`, i.e. the reason that you are rendering dynamic images is for the consumption of a browser?

**If the dynamic images are specific 'per user', or per session:** 
Instead of using session state, generate and deliver the images dynamically with appropriate [Http Caching headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control), and they should then be cached by the browser. You may still need to handle the case for [`If-Modified-Since` requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498135/last-modified-header-in-mvc)

**If the images can be shared between multiple users, or at least re-used by the same user across sessions** then yes, you could store them to disk (e.g. SSD) in a folder configured for appropriate caching (and even precompute the images if you can) and then your `img` links will no longer be dynamic (`http://myserver/images/123456.jpg` ). You will however need to handle cleanup of expired images, and also handle 404 type errors for deleted images. As above, use Http caching headers to reduce unnecessary I/O. However nowadays, caching in memory with a key value / NoSql database is also common, e.g. [Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10558465/314291), which can then scale in the cloud, e.g. [Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/faqs/)